# Post info on server

Tags: blackberry

In my app, i need post some information on server which information gives by user. In simulator  successfully posted the info and get response code 200.

But in mobile no info send to server. no response code receive.

Pls help me.. whats the pbm on it...

Comment: No code ? That is going to be a tough one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append connectionString in URL for different carrier in blackberry device.
for example if use wifi network then your need to open HTTPConnection like:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi");
```

where ";interface=wifi" is connectionString.

In case of simulator connectionString is ";deviceside=true".

[get connection url suffix code from here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/General-way-to-detect-th-network-connection-url-suffix/m-p/677881#M136215)